# Server slowdown when copying files

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have a C# program which queries a database (server3) to determine the files a user is after, then copies those files from (server1) to (server2).

To simplify that further

- C# application is executed on a desktop computer
- Original files are on server1
- Files are to be copied to server2
- Server3 contains the database

When I run this program on my desktop, everything works fine except server1, which seems to almost grind to a holt after about 5 minutes, even though the copying process continues working fine even after 5 minutes.  Any other application/user who try to connect to that server can't.

They just get a spinning cursor which only stops if I stop running the program on my desktop.  For the first 5 minutes into the copying process, everything is fine for everyone.  When going beyond the 5 minute range, the files continue to copy, but that's when others start experiencing connection problems to server1.

I have even tried using `sleep` as I assumed that the slow down was because of too much network activity and/or too much disk I/O activity on server1.  `sleep` did nothing to help, the same problem continues.  So I'm guessing the problem is happening for some other reason.

I am using code similar to this to copy the files

```
while (reader1.read(){
    // system.threading.thread.sleep(2000);
    system.io.file.copy(source, destination);
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: How are you copying the files? If you're just doing a bunch of sequential file copies, it sounds like your server is just under-specced. If you're trying to run many copies in parallel, you should maybe structure your code to be less aggressive.

Comment: I'm copying specific files based on a database query.  Not parallel copying, It's copying 1 file at a time.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Can you show some code?

Comment: I'm using the code `system.io.file.copy(source, destination)`, which runs in a loop based on database query results.

Comment: In a regular `foreach` or `for` loop, not a parallel one?

Comment: Yes, using a regular `while(reader1.read())` as a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article,](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2010/05/10/how-to-copy-very-large-files-across-a-slow-or-unreliable-network.aspx) the main cause of the slowdown is the use of buffering by the file copy.

On Windows Vista or later, it's possible to avoid using buffering by specifying `COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING` to the [`CopyFileEx()` Windows API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363852%28VS.85%29.aspx).

You can specify the P/Invoke as follows:

```
enum CopyProgressResult: uint
{
    PROGRESS_CONTINUE = 0,
    PROGRESS_CANCEL   = 1,
    PROGRESS_STOP     = 2,
    PROGRESS_QUIET    = 3
}

enum CopyProgressCallbackReason: uint
{
    CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED = 0x00000000,
    CALLBACK_STREAM_SWITCH  = 0x00000001
}

delegate CopyProgressResult CopyProgressRoutine(
    long TotalFileSize,
    long TotalBytesTransferred,
    long StreamSize,
    long StreamBytesTransferred,
    uint dwStreamNumber,
    CopyProgressCallbackReason dwCallbackReason,
    IntPtr hSourceFile,
    IntPtr hDestinationFile,
    IntPtr lpData);

[Flags]
enum CopyFileFlags: uint
{
    COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS              = 0x00000001,
    COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE                 = 0x00000002,
    COPY_FILE_OPEN_SOURCE_FOR_WRITE       = 0x00000004,
    COPY_FILE_ALLOW_DECRYPTED_DESTINATION = 0x00000008,
    COPY_FILE_COPY_SYMLINK                = 0x00000800, //NT 6.0+
    COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING                = 0x00001000
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CopyFileEx
(
    string lpExistingFileName,
    string lpNewFileName,
    CopyProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine, 
    IntPtr lpData,
    ref Int32 pbCancel,
    CopyFileFlags dwCopyFlags
);
```

Then call it like this (substituting your own file names);

```
int cancel = 0;
CopyFileEx(@"C:\tmp\test.bin", @"F:\test.bin", null, IntPtr.Zero, ref cancel, CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING);
```

It might be worth trying this and seeing if it helps.

Comment: @oshirowanen it just wants an `int cancel = 0;` to be defined on the preceeding line. (I'll update the sample)

Comment: Code is working, but it's still causing the original problem, i.e. after about 5 minutes all apps/users which need server1 start slowing down until I stop running the copy application from the desktop.

Comment: @oshirowanen Ah well, it was worth a try. Did you read the article I quoted at the start of my answer - it does suggest some other things.